# External Kafka Stream Source in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-data, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am migrating from Streamset to Spring Cloud Data Flow. When I am looking for module list I realized that some of the sources are not listed in Spring Cloud Flow - One of them is KAFKA source.

My question is why external KAFKA source is removed from standard sources list in spring cloud data flow ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not that it is removed, but rather does not exist yet. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues/265

Comment: As of now how we can configure kafka as a source system in SCDF? When it will be available in the list.

Comment: You would need to create a custom source app (example [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-sample/#source). There is a similar SO w/ an [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152714/pollablemessagesource-issue-with-spring-cloud-stream-4-0-0-and-spring-boot-3). Please add a comment to the issue above so that we can get it prioritized sooner. Thanks